# referencing a variable in another function?

Tags: python, variables

I'm an experienced TCL developer and write my own procedures to help myself along. i.e.
a proc i call putsVar, it prints out the value of the variable in a definitave format, so I know which variable it is and what the value is "set foo 1 ; putsVar foo" Result 'foo="1"'
I'd like to do the same kind of thing in python, but not finding the answer :( .
In TCL I use the upvar command since I pass the name of the variable in, then I upvar and can see the value.

I understand that python doesn't have an upvar type mechanism, but with its introspection capaility, I would think this is somewhat trivial, but I'm not finding the answer anywhere.

Here's how i think it should work:

```
def printVar(var):
    valVar = "some mechanism to look up 1 level here to get value of var"
    print str(var) + "=\"" + str(valVar) + "\""

x = "Hello"
printVar("x")
x="Hello"
```

and extended:

```
def foo():
    y = "Hello World"
    printVar("y")

foo()
y="Hello World"
```

Comment: We switched from dynamic scoping for a reason. We also don't treat strings as code whenever it can be avoided, again for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you shouldn't. If your code downright *needs* it, then something is wrong with your design, and you probably should be using explicitly passed dictionaries or objects with proper attributes.

But, to answer the question directly: you can use `sys._getframe`. Just be aware that this might not be portable across Python implementations (i.e. work only on CPython):

```
def get_object(name):
   return sys._getframe(1).f_locals[name]

x = 'foo bar'
print get_object('x')

def foo():
    y = 'baz baf'
    print get_object('y')

foo()
```

Comment: Abosuletly this is the idea.  I use it for internal debugging on the fly, without having to type in all the "pretty stuff" to see what a value is set at. I have seen some other posts, where you can "set" the value using this same mechanism, which I think I probably a bad idea.   Just a simple function that prints some information when i have multiple variable i may be watching.     Thanks for the response

Comment: Is using sys._getframe() better ? more forward compatible, than using inspect ?

Comment: @Mike: inspect.currentframe is not much more portable than sys._getframe (it will return None if not supported, but resulting TypeError might be more confusing than "_getframe not found").

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not 100% clear on what you want but you can expand printVar a bit so that you pass in the name of the variable (as you want it printed) as well as the variable itself.

```
def printVar(var, var_name):
    print "{0} = {1}".format(var_name, var)

>>> x = 5
>>> printVar(x, "x")
x = 5
>>> y = "Hello"
>>> printVar(y, "y")
y = Hello
```

To my knowledge, there's no good way to get a string representation of a variable name. You'll have to provide it yourself.

---

I'll expand it to fit your example a bit better:

```
def printVar(var, var_name):
    if type(var) is type(str()):
        print '{0} = "{1}"'.format(var_name, var)
    else:
        print '{0} = {1}'.format(var_name, var)
>>> printVar(x, "x")
x = 5
>>> printVar(y, "y")
y = "Hello"
```

Comment: I would do def printVar(var, var_name):
    print "{0} = {1}".format(var_name, repr(var))

Comment: @XavierCombelle: You can also use `{1!r}` for that.

Comment: Or use backticks. They're all equivalent.

Comment: @Wallacoloo: Backticks are deprecated in 2 and removed in 3.

Comment: Well sending in the variable name and the value was something I had thought of, but being a programmer, and the information is already defined, why do that. Let the language help you out, probably doesn't add much overhead processing time, and even if it does, I'm just using in the development cycle.   Thanks for the response though.